# Are there any (poorly documented) changes to IntentFilter's and exported components in Android 12?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-12

We use declarations like the following one (Manifest) to link to certain parts of the app:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".some.package.SomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="*.some-domain.com" />
            <data android:path="/native/foo" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

On devices running Android 12, this suddenly stopped working, e.g. scanning a QR code containing a certain URL automatically opens it in the default browser. Prior to Android 12, the system offers to open those URLs in our app when tapping on links like `https://some.domain.com/native/foo/bar/`. I went through the [changelog](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12) and was unable to find anything that could explain this behavior (considering we already set `exported="true"`).

What am I missing and how can I tell the system to offer our app to handle those specific URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE
After test some case, I found you should change your scheme from `https` to non `https` string, such as `your_app_string`. If you still want to use `https` as your scheme, you should check the doordash's [tech blog](https://doordash.engineering/2022/01/25/your-deep-links-might-be-broken-web-intents-and-android-12/).

Your should make the android system can verify your scheme.In simple words,start with android 12(api 31), you need Declare the association between your website and your intent filters by hosting a Digital Asset Links JSON file at the following location:

`https://some.domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

[official doc reference here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#auto-verification)

Comment: hm.. I guess this is about app links, but I'm talking about deep links - actually the URL we use does not exist, we just use it for the scheme. We have no requirement for those URLs to be automatically opened in our app - the chooser is sufficient, but the issue is that there is no chooser anymore. We also target SDK 30 (OS 11), not 31.

Comment: how about change your sheme from `https` to other something like `myapp`

Comment: thanks, moving to a custom scheme fixed the issue. Nice blog post, will need to double-check since we also use app links